# mongoid - how to query by embedded object

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have the following model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in :users

  field :full_name,   :type => String
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :sender, :class_name => "User"

  field :text,        :type => String
end
```

I would like to store `User` and `Message` in separated standalone collections so that they could be queried directly, and I would like to have one copy of user for `sender` in each Message entry. Is my model correct for this kind of request?

And when I have an instance of User `user`, how could I query the messages where `sender = user`?

I've tried:
`Message.where(:sender => user)`
`Message.where('sender.id' => user.id)`
both not work.

only `Message.where('sender.full_name' => user.full_name)` worked, but I don't want to rely on a text field when there's an id field to use.

What's the best way to do that?

**How I save Message/User:**

```
user = User.new
user.full_name = 'larry'
user.save

m = Message.new(:text => 'a text message')
m.sender = user
m.save
```

And it results in the database:

```
> db.users.find({ 'full_name' : 'larry'})
> db.messages.find({})[0]
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f66e5c10364392f7ccd4d74"),
        "text" : "a text message",
        "sender" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4f62e0af03642b3fb54f82b0"),
                "full_name" : "larry"
        }
}
```

Comment: It's correct, mu. You could convert this into answer. But I feel still a little bit confused. Because I always feel `Message.where(:sender => user)` should be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explain by Jordan Durran ( Mongoid lead developer )  in Google group of Mongoid : http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/04e06a8582dbeced#

> You're going to need a separate model if you want to embed the user
>   data  inside the message. When denormalizing like this I generally
>   namespace one  of them, and create a module with the common fields to
>   include in both -  maybe in your case you can call it Sender?

```
class Sender 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  include UserProperties 

  class << self 
    def from_user(user) 
      Sender.new(user.attributes) 
    end 
  end 
end 

class User 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  include UserProperties 
end 

module UserProperties 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern 
  included do 
    field :full_name, type: String 
  end 
end 

class Message 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  embeds_one :sender 
end
```

> You also don't need the :store_in macro on User - by default it's name
>   would be "users".

Comment: Excellent! although that's actually same question posted by me in googlegroup and I forget to go back to check it these days :P. Sadly that I might have to adjust my model again..I've already fall back to use the reference the other day.

Comment: yes I follow the google group it's why I paste the Durran answer here. If you do a question on google group you can link your SO question is you do before.

Comment: yep, I will do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you do.

Your user document is save in his one collection because you use the `store_in` method. And you try save it on an other document ( `Message`)

If you really want 2 collections, you need use `has_one :user` in your `Message` class.

```
class Message

  has_one :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'

end
```

After you can get your message like :

`Message.senders` to have all of your sender.

Comment: Thanks shingara, yes, I want a User and Message stored in separated collections, but I would like to have a copy of User in the Message model as the sender, not a reference. Does it mean I should just `field :sender, :type => User`?

Comment: You need add on your User class a `embedded_in :message`

Comment: Then the user will be stored in Message collection and will not be able to query directly, am I correct?

Comment: Can you add too how you save your Message/User ?